# Regex for contains at least one instance of STRINGA and no instances of STRINGB

Tags: regular-expression, cisco

What regex will match:

contains at least one instance of "1221", and no instances of "7474"

i.e. matches "7777 1221 4543"

but does not match "7777 1221 7474 4543"

I suspect I have to use negative lookaheads?

I am using Cisco IOS (version: IOS XE 3.10.4S)

Comment: you tag `cisco`, you sould tell which OS your are using. Is it cisco os ?

Comment: What program are you using? While this can mathematically be expressed as a regexp, the size of the regexp for “A and not B” can be extremely large, and building that regexp is nontrivlal, **except** for flavors that support negative lookahead. It may be easier to use two regexps and do the “and not” bit in some other way, if that's possible.

Comment: I'm using Cisco IOS (version IOS XE 3.10.4S

Answer (score 1):

using negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*7474).*1221
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dU0lQ8/1)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this, however it didn't work, I suspect maybe because I'm using Cisco IOS?  Response output: 

bdr01.mel11#show ip bgp regexp ^(?!.*7474).*1221
% ?+* follows nothing
% Invalid regular expression

Comment: I don't know what regexp engine Cisco uses. lookarounds probably require a modern PCRE engine.

Comment: I contacted the Cisco TAC for help. They claim it's not possible. So poor :(

Comment: Why post a question about Cisco IOS on a Unix group?

Comment: Because at that point in time I thought the regex engines were roughly similar... plus a guy at work suggested it might bear some fruit. Thanks for your help anyways.